# What is the name of the pattern for managing another class's lifecycle

Tags: design-patterns

Let's say we have Class A and Class B.

Class A's job is just to do X,Y,Z. The problem is it needs to be created, disposed of, and also referenced somewhere for manage these lifecycles.

Class B to the rescue. Class B kind of acts as a factory as it creates the instance but also houses it so it can kill it later.

An example of this would be managing a database connection in an application.

Comment: For database connections, that would usually be some form of the [pool pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern)

Comment: I thought pool would be the closest, but with the usage I intend to use the pool size is 1 and the instance of Class A is completely disposed off after use and another one is spawned.

Comment: Sounds similar to Castle Windsor's Container. I'm not sure this fits with an 'established' design pattern though. There are a number of problems with the functionality that you describe. I'm wondering if this is why it doesn't fit nicely into a known pattern?

Comment: I agree, the functionality is a bit mucky. The example I am giving is doing E2E testing. We only have 1 VM to work with, therefore the connection to it needs to be pooled. Each test gets a new connection and after each test has finished the connection is destroyed.

Comment: In that case isn't it just a Factory with `Create()` and `Destroy()` methods?

Comment: This is more a *responsibility* than a pattern.

Comment: If you are looking to name class B, you could use InstanceManager. Another name that comes to mind is is Container.

Answer (score 0):

I think that will be hard to find a pattern for this. Pattern is not just structured piece of code performing some common task. It is also an intent.

I would say, that just creating, destroying and keeping a reference is not a real OOP intent since the task itself is very abstract.

Also, this "pattern" seem not applicable to languages/frameworks with automatic or semi-automatic garbage collection since there is no need to keep a reference to destroy an object later.